# Click on image div should appear JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

So I am making a section wherein for pc's and laptops when you hover over an image that a div appears over it with some text. I have made this and it works, but when I was looking at the mobile version, I had forgotten you can't hover on mobile. So I thought the best thing to do is probably when you click on the image that the div would appear.

This is where the issues began. I am using shopify so it needs to be dynamic to the light editor.

As you can see I tried some stuff with javascript, tried to add classes with css. I am not sure what the best way is to do this so if anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit: I changed the ID selector to class selectors and tried some new stuff with the javascript.

Heres my code:

```
<div class="uspContainer"> 
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
  
  <div class="uspTextContainer bigScreen">
    <div class="uspIcon">
      {% if block.settings.image != blank %}
         <img src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '100x100'}}" alt="img" class="uspIconImg"> 
           {% else %}
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1,2 %}{% endcapture %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <p class="uspText">{{ block.settings.text }}</p>
  </div>

    <div class="uspTextContainer smallScreen">
    <div class="uspIcon">
      {% if block.settings.image != blank %}
         <img src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '100x100'}}" alt="img" class="uspIconImg"> 
           {% else %}
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1,2 %}{% endcapture %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <p class="uspTextTwo hidden">{{ block.settings.text }}</p>
  </div>
  
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<style>

  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .bigScreen {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

  @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .smallScreen {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }

  .uspContainer 
    {
      display: flex;
    }
  
  .uspTextContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }

  .uspText {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.72);
    color: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
    min-width: 15%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .uspTextContainer:hover .uspText {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

    .uspTextTwo {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.72);
    color: black;
    transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
    min-width: 15%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script>
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".uspIcon");
const textTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".uspTextTwo");
const uspContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.uspContainer');

uspContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('uspIcon')){
          textTwo.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
});
  
  if (uspContainer.classList.contains("smallScreen")) {
    icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    textTwo.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
}

  icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(textTwo.classList.contains('hidden')){
        textTwo.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
});
</script>
```

It gives me the error icon.addEventListener is not a function + tells me all the variables are undefined when i console log.

Comment: Your loop replicates `id`. `id` must be unique and `document.getElementById` merely returns the first possible match. Try using selector on classes like [`document.querySelectorAll('.uspTextContainer')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score -1):

something like from your code that maybe the blocks has not only one block, so if you just use the `querySelector`, you just select the first element, not all elements

you can use the event capture on element `uspContainer`

```js
<script>
var uspContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.uspContainer');


uspContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('uspIcon')){
       // so you click the icon
        // do your action
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have done this but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: You can not use `addEventListener` on a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches). You have to loop its elements.